# why would data have different footprints for disk versus memory?

Tags: python, memory

"We have the 2015 Yellow Cab NYC Taxi data as 12 CSV files on S3... This data is about 20GB on disk or 60GB in RAM."

i came across this observation while trying out [dask](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/01/12/dask-dataframes), a python framework for handling out of memory datasets.

can someone explain to me why there is a 3x difference? id imagine it has to do with python objects but am not 100% sure.

thanks!

Comment: sorry :)

df = dd.read_csv('s3://dask-data/nyc-taxi/2015/*.csv')

dd.read_csv() is analogous to pandas read_csv().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading from a CSV on disk into a structured data frame object in memory.  The two things are not at all analogous.  The CSV data on disk is a single string of text.  The data in memory is a complex data structure, with multiple data types, internal pointers, etc.

The CSV itself is not taking up any RAM.  There is a complex data structure that is taking up RAM, and it was populated using data sourced from the CSV on disk.  This is not at all the same thing.

To illustrate the difference, you could try reading the CSV into an actual single string variable and seeing how much memory that consumes.  In this case, it would effectively be a single CSV string in memory:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    data=csvFile.read()
```

Comment: In many cases it's not necessary to have all the data in ram at once. Just iterate over the csvFile object if you can make do with one row at a time.

Comment: Correct.  Certainly `readlines()` is better than `read()` is many cases.  I don't think either would suite the OP's situation though.  Note that the whole point of the little exercise at the end of this answer is to get the entire thing into memory at once, simply to measure its memory footprint so that it can be compared to the memory footprint that the CSV file has on disk.